# How to create every combination possible between two array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two arrays of objects, i.e. origin and destination. I am trying to find out all possible combinations that can be made from the two arrays to make a final array.
Example:

```
origin = [
 {
   id: 1,
   regionName: "Africa North"
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   regionName: "Africa West"
 }
];

destination: [
 { 
   id: 5,
   regionName: "Gulf"
 },
 {
   id: 8,
   regionName: "Middle East"
 },
 {
   id: 9,
   regionName: "Central America"
 }
]
```

The final array should give me,

```
 finalArray = [
   {
    originRegion: "Africa North",
    destinationRegion: "Gulf",
    ts: "1606370160"
   },
   {
    originRegion: "Africa North",
    destinationRegion: "Middle East",
    ts: "1606370160"
   },
   {
    originRegion: "Africa North",
    destinationRegion: "Central America",
    ts: "1606370160"
   },
   {
    originRegion: "Africa West",
    destinationRegion: "Gulf",
    ts: "1606370160"
   },
   {
    originRegion: "Africa West",
    destinationRegion: "Middle East",
    ts: "1606370160"
   },
   {
    originRegion: "Africa West",
    destinationRegion: "Central America",
    ts: "1606370160"
   },
 ]
```

I tried looking for some Permutations and combinations on two array of objects but didn't find get any suitable answer.
This is what I am trying:

```
useEffect(() => {
        var origin = [
            {
                id: 1,
                regionName: "Africa North"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                regionName: "Africa West"
            }
        ];

        var destination = [
            {
                id: 5,
                regionName: "Gulf"
            },
            {
                id: 8,
                regionName: "Middle East"
            },
            {
                id: 9,
                regionName: "Central America"
            }
        ];

        var finalArray = []

        for (var i = 0; i < origin.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < destination.length; j++) {
                finalArray.push(origin[i].regionName + destination[j].regionName)
            }
        }

        console.log("finalArray", finalArray)
    }, []);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you tried to change those solution per your requirement?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to change it as we speak. I am sharing what I am trying.

Comment: not sure what exactly is useEffect and ts, but you could modify your for loops to get desired output:  for (var i = 0; i < origin.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < destination.length; j++) {
                finalArray.push({originRegion: origin[i].regionName, destinationRegion: destination[j].regionName, ts: Date.now()});
            }
        }

Comment: @RahulR. Thank you so much for saving the day. I am writing code in React.js and hooks, so I have used useEffect and ts is just the time-stamp.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have the double looping part, but the object you are pushing into your array isn't what you say you expect. You are doing simple string concatenation.

```
origin[i].regionName + destination[j].regionName
```

Here is what I think is a more "react" way to loop over the data and return a result array. Reduce the `origin` array into a new array, mapping in the combined object with the `destination` array.

```
origin.reduce(
  (result, origin) => [
    ...result,
    ...destination.map((destination) => ({
      originreagion: origin.regionName,
      destinationRegion: destination.regionName,
      ts: "1606370160" // <-- set your real timestamp here
    }))
  ],
  []
);
```

```js
const origin = [
  {
    id: 1,
    regionName: "Africa North"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    regionName: "Africa West"
  }
];

const destination = [
  {
    id: 5,
    regionName: "Gulf"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    regionName: "Middle East"
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    regionName: "Central America"
  }
];

const result = origin.reduce(
  (result, origin) => [
    ...result,
    ...destination.map((destination) => ({
      originreagion: origin.regionName,
      destinationRegion: destination.regionName,
      ts: "1606370160"
    }))
  ],
  []
);

console.log(result)
```